# Alternendo for differentials : can a differential denominator be zero?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $\frac{dA(x)}{dx} = \frac{dB(t)}{dt} $

I can write

$\frac{dA}{dB} = \frac{dx}{dt}$

for which dB must be non-zero. But, since dB is a differential (= infinitesimal but finite) the above relation must hold true always.

Am I wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: It depends on the framework. In the standard framework this reasoning isn't valid, but can be cleaned up to give valid reasoning. In any framework you should really be careful about what this means: what is $\frac{dA}{dB}$ a function of? Is it a function of $B$?

Comment: what I take from this is that, dB, for it to be zero or non-zero, is first related to A or equivalently dA. We have to get to that function as you have said. If that dA/dB is indeed a function of B then?

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right in your reasoning. $dB$ will tend to 0 but will always be non-zero. And if this did not hold, we would not be able to solve differential equations by mere separation and certain other methods.